# Avoid re-running migrations in spring test suite

Tags: spring, spring-boot, junit, integration-testing

I am working on a codebase that has approx 300+ spring integration tests, that are inherited from this class

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@DirtiesContext(classMode=DirtiesContext.ClassMode.BEFORE_CLASS) //enable migration if IT ran before
@ActiveProfiles(Constants.SpringProfiles.TEST)
@SpringBootTest
@Transactional
public abstract class BaseTest extends BaseMockitoTest { .... }
```

What happens with this config is ofcourse it reinitialize the complete spring application, which takes a lot of time in our overall integration suite. I wanted to understand if I can change this configuration to something that avoid reinitialized context.

I have already tried removing @DirtiesContext, but that did not help.

What I want is, spring initialization and migrations run during initialization should remain as it is, and remaining stuff should be rolled back upon test execution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeeh, @DirtiesContext is for the lazy :P - it will catch you, when the initialization time and/or the amount of test cases increases.

Our database migration is a separate step in our build chain (including migrating production data).

Before we run our test cases, we setup the database with the current schema - that's a seperate step in the chain, too. So our integration tests assume the schema is correct. If the creation of the schema would fail, we don't run the tests, since the report won't be meaningful anyway.

I like this approach, because we can manage and analyze integration tests and migration test separately, meaning: integration tests *can* run, even though the migration failed. And they can run parallel, so you should get feedback a bit earlier.

Edit: In addition to Paul's statement: Some of our integration tests perform tasks within a separate transaction, and we can't assert the outcome of those executions :-/

Answer (score 2):

What do you mean by "remaining stuff should be rolled back upon test execution" ?

The normal approach is not to have DirtiesContext but just SpringBootTest and make your tests transactional so they rollback any added data at the end of each test. See:

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.3.7.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#testcontext-tx-enabling-transactions